# lots of different variables into one data frame

Tags: r

I need to get all the different variables (picking and choosing from one data set) into a new data set.

I have used subset and now it is saying it has 0 observations for 102 variables. Where have the observations gone? (I have tried all other things, "c", cbind, merge, data.frame. They all say that values must be logical or for data.frame, lengths don't match).

So if I do this:

```
prevsex1<-subset(hhmemshp2,((hhmemshp2$commun)&(hhmemshp2$hhnum)& 
            (hhmemshp2$surveyyr)& (hhmemshp2$surveypl)&
            year& (hhmemshp2$yrborn)& (hhmemshp2$usyr1)& 
            (hhmemshp2$hhmemshp)& (hhmemshp2$sex)& 
            (hhmemshp2$allmig1)& (hhmemshp2$manmig1)& 
            (hhmemshp2$femmig1)& (hhmemshp2$allage)& 
            (hhmemshp2$manage)& (hhmemshp2$femage1)& 
            (hhmemshp2$alllive)& (hhmemshp2$manlive)& 
            (hhmemshp2$femlive)& (hhmemshp2$weight)))
```

I get:

```
Error in (hhmemshp2$commun) & (hhmemshp2$hhnum) & (hhmemshp2$surveyyr) &  : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
In addition: Warning message:
In (hhmemshp2$commun) & (hhmemshp2$hhnum) & (hhmemshp2$surveyyr) &  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and the code you tried.

Comment: `hhmemshp2$commun)&(hhmemshp2$hhnum)&....` doesn't look right.  Are these all logical columns?

Comment: I thought they were but I don't know anymore... how do I check whether they are logical columns?

Comment: you may want something like `dplyr::select(hhmemshp2, commun, hhnum, ...)`

Comment: `is.logical`, but I am not sure what you are doing with all these `&`.  If you want to select the columns `subset(hhmemshp2, select=c(...))`

Comment: ahhh I understand what you mean - I have all these columns and I just want to make them into a new data set. I don't know why this is so complicated. I tried data. frame and it says they are different lengths so I couldn't do that. If I try to do if logical, I get this; Error in (hhmemshp2$commun) & (hhmemshp2$hhnum) & (hhmemshp2$surveyyr) &  : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
In addition: Warning message:
In (hhmemshp2$commun) & (hhmemshp2$hhnum) & (hhmemshp2$surveyyr) &  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to subset the columns, use the `select` argument in `subset`

```
data(mtcars)
df1 <- subset(mtcars, select=c('mpg', 'wt'))
```

Or

```
df1 <- subset(mtcars, select=names(mtcars)[c(1,6)])
```

Comment: okay, that worked!!! Yay!!! And then there is a variable that is significantly shorter than others.. and I got stuck again. prevsex2<-subset(hhmemshp2,select=c("commun","hhnum","surveyyr","surveypl","yrborn", "usyr1", "hhmemshp",
                           "sex", "allmig1", "manmig1", "femmig1", "allage","manage", "femage",
                           "alllive", "manlive", "femlive", "weight")) ------this worked!!
prevsex2$year<-(1900:2014) and if I do this, I get: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "year", value = 1900:2014) : 
  replacement has 115 rows, data has 114479

Comment: @Rachel I guess after you subset the `hhmemshp2` i.e. `prevsex2`, you are creating a `year` column.  It is better to check the nrow of `prevsex2` and the `length(1900:2014)`.  It should be the same or be a multiple of `nrow(prevsex2)`, otherwise, use `?rep`

Comment: Because year variable isn't a part of hhmemshp2 data set so I thought I would do it separately and now it's saying that it's too short??

Comment: I don't think I am allowed to use repetition.. is there any other way for me to add year to the data set?

Comment: @Rachel You need to make both the lengths the same, Try `prevsex2$year <- rep(1900:2014, length.out=nrow(prevsex2))`  If you are not allowed repetition, you can create a `list` which can take unequal length for `list` elements.

Comment: okay, so there is no way around it. Great! THANK YOU SO SO MUCH! YOU ARE A GENIUS!!! I hope you have a lovely sunday!

Comment: @Rachel Place it in a `list` i.e. `lst <- list(as.list(prevsex2), year=1990:2014)`

Comment: It worked absolutely great. I've checked the mark thingy as well. :)))

Answer (score 1):

I may not be understanding you, but if you want to just extract certain columns, use, e.g.,

```
df <- mtcars[,c("mpg","wt")]
head(df,2)
#               mpg    wt
# Mazda RX4      21 2.620
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21 2.875
```

So in your case it would be:

```
prevsex1<-hhmemshp2[,c("commun","hhnum","surveyyr",...)]
```